# How can I link JQuery AND another JS file to my html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help linking my JS file to my html file after I linked jQuery from Google CDN. I could do   and put the code inside, but it makes my code look untidy.

This is what I'm doing:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script src="images/script.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

After that, my code does not work. However, when I put it into script tags, it does. I'm linking to script.js correctly, but the code doesn't activate when I try clicking on something. What can I do to fix this?

The code I created was:

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('show-description');
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the code you created as well. Also, check the console for errors.

Comment: `However, when I put it into script tags, it does.` If it's a script it needs to be put in script tags.

Comment: So I can't link it outside of the html document?

Comment: @chRyNaN, I believe OP is meaning doing `<script>code</script>` instead of `<script src="..."></script>`

Comment: Do view source of your page, click on the `script.js` and see if it takes you to the desired file.

Comment: Can you show us the content of your <head> tag if you are loading both in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your code within document ready function from jQuery. The issue is your DOM is not ready at the time you defined the onclick handler.

[jquery document ready function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('div').on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('show-description');
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: @Edwin Mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem. Also try not to put your script tags inside the head. Instead put them just before closing </body> tag. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your file pathway for your script.js file in regards to your html file.

Comment: Could you please add more details to the solution you provided?